# Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal -- Algolia Search

Tags: swift, xcode, algolia

I am trying to convert my code to latest swift version but I can not convert following code.

**// @objc public var urlParameters: [String: String] = [:]**

```
 let requestOptions = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions.urlParameters["optionalFilters"] = ["category:Book", "author:John Doe"]
```

[image]

I could not find the best solution for it. How can I do it?

Comment: what is the type of your `urlParameters ` ? is it like `var urlParameters: [String: Any]?`

Answer (score 0):

You dictionary `value` parameter is `String`, but you trying to set the array of `String`. To do that change the signature to string-array of string:

```
var urlParameters: [String: [String]] = [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing your urlParameter is of type

```
var urlParameters = [String: Any]()
```

Here, you will find that `urlParameters` is of type dictionary with String key and values are of array of strings.

On First hand, We need to declare it as:

```
var urlParameters = [String: [String]]()
```

**Alternative:**

or we can use `AnyObject` on place of `[String]` as Update in Swift 3: JSON collection (dictionary / array) can only contain value types.

> Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific types:
>
> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
>
> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

```
var urlParameters = [String: AnyObject]()
```